# R: why is my ggplot geom_point() symbol not visible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to place a symbol on the lowest point in a certain time series, which I have plotted with ggplot's geom_line. However, the geom_point is not showing up on the plot. I have myself successfully used geom_point for this kind of thing before by following hadley's example [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/toolbox.r) (search for 'highest <- subset' to get the relevant assignment) so I know very well that it can be done. I'm just at a loss to spot what I have done differently here that is causing it not to display. I'm guessing it's something straightforward like a missing argument or similar - easy points for a pair of fresh eyes, I think.

Minimal example follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
fstartdate <- as.Date('2009-06-01')

set.seed(12345)
x <- data.frame(mydate=seq(as.Date("2003-06-01"), by="month", length.out=103),myval=runif(103, min=180, max=800))
lowest <- subset(x, myval == min(x[x$mydate >= fstartdate,]$myval))

thisplot <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = x, aes(mydate, myval), colour = "blue", size = 0.7) +
    geom_point(data = lowest, size = 5, colour = "red")

print(thisplot)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point appears if you add the aesthetic:

```
thisplot + geom_point(
  data = lowest, 
  aes(mydate, myval), 
  size = 5, colour = "red"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for me, though I don't know why I need aes this time but not in other scripts! (Nor is it used in the example in the book - odd.)

Comment: Or move that mapping into the ggplot call, which is probably what the book example does.

Comment: I think it does. That part of the chapter is quite cluttered, as the example builds a lot of additional structure on top of the original call, but that original call - as far as I can make out - is `(unemp <- qplot(date, unemploy, data=economics, geom = "line", xlab = "", ylab = "No. unemployed (1000s)"))`. So yes, it looks like I should have traced it back up the page a bit further. Live and learn.